# Select Always Returns 0 When run within different program

Tags: sockets

I am facing a strange problem, maybe it's straightforward but my lack of much socket knowledge is not helping either.

I have created a socket program and it works perfectly when run in a separate program i.e within main separately as an independent exe. As you can see in the code, the socket fd returned is always 3 when run in this separate program.

When I copy the same piece of code and integrate this to another server program which which has it's own fd's opened, the select always returns 0 no matter what. The fd created in this case with my program is always 6.

See my program below. there is no problem in this piece of code, it's just when this is been run inside another server, the select always returns 0.

Can I create a new UDP socket fd when there is already one existing in the program. 
Why is this happening when my socket fd is different then already opened within the program.

Why is this happening, can anyone please guide me what to do or any pointers would be helpful.

```
#define MY_TIMEOUT_S    5   
    int mySock;
    if ((mySock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Cannot create UDP socket");
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in myAddr;
    myAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    myAddr.sin_port         = 0;
    myAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = INADDR_ANY;
    memset(&(myAddr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);
    if (bind(mySock, (struct sockaddr*)&myAddr, 
            sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        perror("Cannot bind UDP socket to desired port");
        close(mySock);
        return -1;
    }

    // here send to remote target host on udp socket and port 

    char buf[MAX_UDP_PACKET_SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in theirAddr;
    int addrLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    fd_set readSet, curReadSet;
    FD_ZERO(&readSet);
    FD_SET(mySock, &readSet);
    int maxFD = mySock;
    while (true) {
        struct timeval timeOutTV = {MY_TIMEOUT_S, 0};

        memcpy(&curReadSet, &readSet, sizeof(fd_set));

        int selectRet = select(maxFD+1, &curReadSet, NULL, NULL, &timeOutTV);
        cout<<"select value =" <<selectRet<<endl;

        if (selectRet == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                continue; // Interrupted by signal, retry
            }
            close(mySock);
            return -1;

        } else if (selectRet == 0) {
            close(mySock);
            return -1;
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(mySock, &curReadSet)) {
            int numBytes = recvfrom(mySock, buf, MAX_UDP_PACKET_SIZE, 0,
                    (struct sockaddr*)&theirAddr, (socklen_t*)&addrLen);
            if (numBytes == -1) {
                close(mySock);
            }   

        }
    }
```

Adding some details from lsof output

1) This is the target where I have to send my data
 sudo lsof -a -p 16061

target 16061 root    3r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 153467 pipe
target 16061 root    4u  IPv4 153470      0t0    UDP *:3290
target 16061 root    5u  sock    0,6      0t0 153471 can't identify protocol
target 16061 root    6u  IPv4 153472      0t0    TCP *:3290 (LISTEN)
target 16061 root    7u   raw             0t0 153473 00000000:0001->00000000:0000 st=07

2) This is my  above piece of code when run in a separate exe, in which only this is the code running inside main
as the FD=3 works fine

sudo lsof -a -p 16112

myProg 16112 root    0u   CHR  136,4      0t0      7 /dev/pts/4
myProg 16112 root    1u   CHR  136,4      0t0      7 /dev/pts/4
myProg 16112 root    2u   CHR  136,4      0t0      7 /dev/pts/4
myProg 16112 root    3u  IPv4 153564      0t0    UDP *:60503

3) This is the web server where I integrated my same above piece of code which is working independently, but not now

this is the output of my web server running

webServ 18431 root    3u  unix 0xc09f9b00      0t0 157975 socket
webServ 18431 root    4u  IPv4     157976      0t0    UDP *:8080
webServ 18431 root    5u  IPv4     157977      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)

now I send request and on the server side my new integrated code is executed and I put an infinite loop and did not close the socket just to show the lsof output

4) Output after my integration

webServ 18449 root    3u  unix 0xc09f9b00      0t0 157975 socket
webServ 18449 root    4u  IPv4     157976      0t0    UDP *:8080
webServ 18449 root    5u  IPv4     157977      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
webServ 18449 root    6u  IPv4     158389      0t0    UDP *:48057

The only difference is when integrated to the server the socket FD is different that's the only difference.

Hope this helps in answering my question.

I am not sure why this is happening. Please help

Comment: Perhaps `select` with `maxFd + 1` would help?

Comment: Added some details from lsof.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `select` with `maxFd + 1` would help?

**Edit**: I've looked again at your code (although you've probably already resolved it yourself by now). I have three suggestions.

Firstly, when you `bind` the socket, `myAddr.sin_port` is `0`. So an ephemeral port number is selected. This port number differs between your myProg and webServ programs:

```
myProg  16112 root 3u IPv4 153564 0t0 UDP *:60503  
webServ 18449 root 6u IPv4 158389 0t0 UDP *:48057
```

So I'm puzzled as to what port number you've been using to send UDPs to myProg.

Secondly, your timeout for `select` is 5 seconds, after which you close the socket and go away. How do you know you'll receive a packet within 5 seconds of opening the port?  To ensure this, the sending program will need to (for example) continually attempt to send a packet every 4 seconds or less, which doesn't seem reasonable.

Thirdly, which is likely a minor point but could possibly be your problem, in:

```
        if (numBytes == -1) {
            close(mySock);
        }
```

you omit the `return -1;` you use elsewhere, and so you'll be stuck in an infinite loop if `recvfrom` returns an error such as EINTR. Also, calling `perror` would be nice here, and elsewhere.

Finally, the comment:

```
  // here send to remote target host on udp socket and port
```

is incorrect, you are *receiving*.

Comment: I am sorry, actually I am trying different options so I changed it to maxFD, but I also tried with maxFD+1, as specified, it works perfectly when run in an independent program. Edited the main post

Answer (score 0):

Make that:

```
int maxFD = mySock + 1;
```

The [man page for select(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) says:

> ```
> int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
>            fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
> ```
>
> *nfds* is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, **plus 1**.

Comment: I am sorry, actually I am trying different options so I changed it to maxFD, but I also tried with maxFD+1, as specified, it works perfectly when run in an independent program.Edited the main post